# How to prevent Firefox extensions/add-ons from being disabled/uninstalled

Tags: firefox, extension

I'd like to know if there is a way to prevent me or others from disabling or uninstalling Firefox extensions/add-ons (I'm on 66.0.3).
(Am using Leechblock but I catch myself every so often just disabling it an mindlessly indulging).

Thank you for every help

Answer (score 2):

This is precisely the kind of task that [*Policies for Firefox for Enterprise*](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/products/firefox-enterprise/policies-customization-enterprise) were created for. You may [lock extensions](https://github.com/mozilla/policy-templates/tree/v1.6#extensions) based on their ID. If you are not sure where to find the *extension ID*, look inside the xpi file, the `manifest.json` contains the ID as well.

Add that ID to a suitable policy, for Firefox 66.0 (or 60.6 ESR) on Linux that would look like this:

```
$ cat /usr/lib/firefox-esr/distribution/policies.json
{ "policies": { "Extensions": { "Locked": ["https-everywhere@eff.org"] } } }
```

Note that *json* files are just one way of configuring such policies, e.g. they are fully integrated into Windows AD or Local Group Policy, using those is likely preferable on applicable platforms.

*Consider switching to Extended Support Releases (ESR). Firefox changes at such a rapid pace, most configurations you apply to mainline releases are often going to cause issues after just a few months.*